# Runtime Problem(Non zero exit condition) Python

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I am writing a code to calculate the four times summation of gcd(i,j,k,l)**4 for every 1<=i

I have tried calculating the permutations of range(n) and then iterating over it all through to check when i

```
def solve(n):
    l=range(1,n+1)
    length = n
    items=l
    def inner(ix=[]):
        do_yield = len(ix) == length - 1
        for i in range(0, length):
            if i in ix: #avoid duplicates
                continue
            if do_yield:
                yield tuple([items[y] for y in ix + [i]])
            else:
                for p in inner(ix + [i]):
                    yield p
    t=inner()
        #rr=list(pp(list(range(1,n+1)),4))
    #l=''.join(l)
    #=list(l)
    #t=pp(list(l))
    #print(t)
    result=0
    for j in list(t):
        #print("j",j)
        if j[0]<j[1] and j[1]<j[2] and j[2]<j[3]:
                #result=j[0]
                #for k in j[1:]:
                    #result=self.gcd(result,k)
            result=result+1
                #su=su+self.fast(result,4)
    print(result%1000000007)
#ob=Solution()
for i in range(int(input())):
    n=input()
    n=int(n)
    solve(n)
```

How can I avoid this NZEC(Runtime Error) in python ..I am very much  stressed over removing this error while coding in python 3.5.
Below is the code I implemented...